# Unable to process file in SQR process due to special character

Tags: encoding, special-characters, peoplesoft, file-encodings, sqr

I am currently working in SQR process, and had encountered an issue during file processing as it results to error due to special character, slanted apostrophe (’). It is a flat file saved as **UTF-8**. I tried changing it as **ANSI** and worked well, but how do I make my code work without changing the encoding?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Could you update the question to include the error logs, the file in question and maybe a piece of code that has problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your open statement, try adding:

```
ENCODING=UTF-8
```